# Angular 4 ngFor & ngIf

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if

I'm looking to count the number of quizzes that have been completed in my array, that are equal to "level 1".

Whenever I try to display the count of items that are equal to level 1 in the progressList, it will display the number for all of the items in the progressList array.

How would I display the number of items that have been completed that are equal to Level 1?

```
 <div *ngFor="let levels of progressList | slice: 0:1; let i = index" align="center">
          <p *ngIf="levels.level == 1"> You've Completed {{progressList?.length}}/4 Lessons! </p>
        </div>
```

***EDIT w/ Array****

complete: "Complete",
level: 1,
user_id:"email@email.com"

complete: "Complete",
level: 1,
user_id:"email@email.com"

complete: "Complete",
level: 1,
user_id:"email@email.com"

complete: "Complete",
level: 2,
user_id:"email@email.com"

complete: "Complete",
level: 2,
user_id:"email@email.com"

Comment: what is the issue with this?

Comment: may be you can do filtering: instead of" let levels of progressList" you can use something like: let levels of  progressList.filter(k=>k.level===1), and use "ngIf" at all

Comment: It's displaying all the items in the array progressList, and not the items that are equal to level 1 @Sajeetharan

Comment: Counting and other aggregate functions are best done in the component, not in the template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following, probably your level is of type string

```
<p *ngIf="levels.level === '1'"> You've Completed {{progressList?.length}}/4 Lessons! </p>
```

**`EDIT`**

ngIf is not used to filter data. it is to show the elements when condition is met. you can do this to show the count in component.ts

completedCount : any;

```
this.completedCount = progressList.filter(t=>t.level ==1).length;
```

and in template

```
<p> You've Completed {{this.completedCount}}/4 Lessons! </p>
```

Comment: This didn't seem to work. I have 5 items in my array, 3 of which are labeled level 1. My result I'm getting is " 5/4 Lessons Complete!"

Comment: can you post your array.

Comment: Just posted - I'm using a number not a string as my "level" item

Comment: ok the problem is your ngIf works its just that progressList is always the same list

Comment: Right - That progressList is going to grow so I'd like to essentially filter by the levels that are equal to 1

Comment: Got it working! Thank you! Just curious , what does the t=>t represent?